# Visual Studio show control properties and events at the same time

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2015

For Controls in WinForms while using the designer I would like to display both Properties and Events for a control at the same time.

[image: Properties Window]

The New Window option is greyed out in Visual Studios Window Drop down when the properties window has focus not allowing me to create a second instance.

I find I spend a lot of time switching between the two.  I use the form designer extensively and events to navigate to specific code quickly.  Any help would be appreciated!